# Prevent extra space when setting variable on Windows command line

Tags: windows, batch

When setting a variable like this:

```
> set foo=hello && echo test
```

then the value of the variable foo contains an extra unwanted space:

```
> echo "%foo%"
"hello "
```

How do I prevent this extra space? It disappears when I omit the `&& echo test` part, but I need to use `&&` for other reasons.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`set foo=hello&& echo test`

works fine over here,

`echo "%foo%"`

prints

`"hello"`

:)

Comment: accepted, but now I'm curious how you would set a value ending with &&. Escaping with ^ doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I can't figure it out either! Escaping just makes the && carry on to when you USE the variable, but putting ""s around them makes it accept the string fine - pity it then has ""s around it.

Comment: And that is why people hate `cmd.exe`

Comment: I dunno, with cygwin and a bit - a lot - of scripting in python and c it's pretty workable. Rather have a windows-y bash, but what are you gonna do.

Comment: @wcoenen: Just use `set "foo=hello&&" in that case. Quoting helps sometimes, you know :-). Of course, when using the variable you still need to be careful to not let the `&` through unquoted. If you know how many parsing passes run over your variables you can also embed the escape characters directly.

Answer (score 18):

You can do this

```
set "foo=hello" && echo test
```

Comment: This is the answer.  With delayedexpansion you can even do:`set "foo=hello" && echo !foo!` and it will return `hello`.  This was helpful.  Thanks

Comment: Yes, this should be the right answer

Comment: This is the answer I was hoping for. The currently accepted answer while works makes for much less readable .bat files

Answer (score 1):

As indicated by the other answers,
spaces at the end of a `set` command are significant,
so if you type

```
set foo=hello & echo test
```

or even

```
set foo=hello␣
```

(where `␣` represents a space),
`%foo%` gets set to the six-character string `h`, `e`, `l`, `l`, `o`,  .

I had a similar problem with space when `echo`ing a string to an output file. 
Not surprisingly (in light of the above),

```
echo hello >myfile
```

writes the six-character string `h`, `e`, `l`, `l`, `o`,    (plus CR and LF)
to the file, while

```
echo hello> myfile
```

does not include the space. 
But spaces at the end of the command line are still a problem. 
If, for some reason, you say

```
echo hello>myfile␣
```

then you get a space at the end of the output. 
When I removed the space after the filename,
the space at the end of the output disappeared.

Weird, but this worked for me.

Comment: Is this intended to be a comment or an answer?

Answer (score 1):

```
set "foo=hello"
```

This helped me heaps in this line

```
FOR /f "tokens=2 delims=><" %%a IN ('TYPE %GCV_CONFIG_FILE% ^| FIND "<%GCV_VALUE_NAME%>"') DO SET "%GCV_VARIABLE_NAME%=%%a" && echo %GCV_VARIABLE_NAME%=%%a >> %SessionLOG%
```

Took me a while to figure out how to remove space the end of the variable.
Hope this helps someone